# Running a shell script from node - ERROR { [Error: Cannot find module 'xxx'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using node 4.4.2. I receive the following error when calling a .sh file on ubuntu linux.

> ERROR { [Error: Cannot find module 'src/util/buildscripts/build.sh'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

```
        var sh = require.resolve('src/util/buildscripts/build.sh'),
            profile = require.resolve('profiles/app.profile.js'),
            ls = spawn(sh, '--profile', profile]);
        });
```

The location for build.sh seems correct, but the error 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' appears misleading to me as I am not try to import a module but only to open .sh file in a child process.

Notes I have a very similar version for Windows which works completely fine example below:

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

```
        var bat = require.resolve('../src/util/buildscripts/build.bat'),
            profile = require.resolve('../profiles/app.profile.js'),
            ls = spawn(bat, ['--profile', profile]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using shelljs and this command:

```
sed('-i', 's/\r//', 'src/util/buildscripts/*.sh');
```

The problem was caused by wrong line ending.

Answer (score 0):

The path you wrote for the Windows version is different than the failing version. Are you sure the Ubuntu one is right?

Comment: Thanks, but I I have tried also with             var bat = require.resolve('../src/util/buildscripts/build.sh'),
                profile = require.resolve('../profiles/app.profile.js'),
                ls = spawn(bat, ['--bin', 'java', '--profile', profile]); and does not work.